# Move Archive Title to Entry Title - Genesis

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I’m using the centric child of genesis theme where I’ve created a custom post type portfolio and and created a portfolio archive page to show up my portfolio. Now when I added “Archive Headline”, it is showing as h1 class acrhive title before the loop, but I want it to show up as entry title like normal page. Can you p[lease help me to do that. I’ve tried several things on internet but none of them actually helped.